# How to iterate a list inside of a JSON object using Kotlin

Tags: json, kotlin

I am receiving a JSON object from an HTTP request using the Fuel library that looks like:

```
{
 'items': ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']
}
```

My code for getting the JSONobject is:

```
Fuel.get("get_cameras").responseJson { request, response, result -> 
    var my_json = result.get().obj()    
}
```

How can I iterate over the 'items' key?  I have tried:

```
 for (items in  my_json) {}
```

but it says it doesn't have an iterator() method.  I am coming from Python and am probably thinking about this in the wrong way because I see plenty of other seemingly similar questions but none seem to be related to what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to first get a hold of the array nested in your object with the `"items"` key, and then you can iterate over that array. The basic way to do this (if you're sure that it only contains strings) would be to loop over its indexes and call `getString` on the array for each index:

```
val my_json = result.get().obj()
val items = my_json.getJSONArray("items")

for (i in 0 until items.length()) {
    val item = items.getString(i)
    // use item
}
```

---

If you don't want to deal with indexes while iterating, you could wrap the iteration of a `JSONArray` into an extension function:

```
fun JSONArray.forEachString(action: (String) -> Unit) {
    for (i in 0 until length()) {
        action(getString(i))
    }
}
```

Which could then be used like this:

```
val items = my_json.getJSONArray("items")
items.forEachString { item ->
    // use item
}
```

---

You *could* extend the `JSONArray` class with an `iterator` function as well if you really wanted to iterate the array with a regular for loop, but it would be more trouble than it's worth.